# React Native Invariant Violation "Main" has not been registered with react-native-track-player

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-player

I am using React-native to build an app that will use audio. Everything was set up correctly and installed with the latest updates. However, whenever I add

`import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player'`

it gives me an error that says

`Invariant Violation : "Main" has not been registered. This can happen if *Metro is run from the wrong folder...`

Comment: Did you create the metro bundler using `npm start` or did it open automatically?

Comment: I used ```expo start``` to start my application